# C programming - array / value of a pointer comparisson

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I don't have much C experience or knowledge and I got stuck with some homework problem,

I try to build a program to find the min and max of an array using `(3/2)*n` comparisons, I went through a lot of Q&A here and it helped a lot, now everything with it is ok other than a weird problem I can't seem to solve.

When I try to **compare** `if(a[0]>a[1]) or if(*(a)>*(a+1))` everything is ok, 
when I try to use else after those phrases or try to `if(a[1]>a[0])` or `if(*(a+1)>*(a))` then the program dies.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void maximum(int *a, int n, int *max, int *min);

    int main()
    {
        int i;
        int number;
        int *max;
        int *min;
        int *a;
        puts("hello, pls enter the number of numbers");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        a = (int*)calloc(number,sizeof(int));
        puts("enter the numbers");
        for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
            puts("before");
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
            puts("after");
        }

       puts("ok");
        maximum(a,number,max,min);
        printf("min is %d, max is %d",*min,*max);
        return(0);


    }

    void maximum(int *a, int n, int *max, int *min)
    {
        int i;
        int temp;
        int tempmax;
        int tempmin;

        if(n==0)
            {
                puts("come on, be serius");
                return(0);
            }
        if(n==1)
            {
                puts("the number you entered is the min and the max but where is the challenge?");
                *min=*max=a[0];
            }
        puts("check3");

       **if(*(a+1)>*(a))
        {
            *max=a[1];
            *min=a[0];
        }**



        /*if(a[0]>a[1])
        {
            *max=a[0];
            *min=a[1];
        }else
        {
            *max=a[1];
            *min=a[0];
        }

        for(i==2;i<(n-2);i=i+2)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            {
                tempmax=a[i];
                tempmin=a[i+1];
            }else
            {
                tempmin=a[i];
                tempmax=a[i+1];
            }
            if(tempmax>*max)
                *max=tempmax;
            if(tempmin<*min)
                *min=tempmin;
        }
    puts("check5");
        if((n%2)==1)
        {
            if(a[n-1]<*min)
                *min=a[n-1];
            if(a[n-1]>*max)
                *max=a[n-1];
        }/*else
        {
            if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            {
                tempmax=a[i];
                tempmin=a[i+1];
            }else
            {
                tempmin=a[i];
                tempmax=a[i+1];
            }
            if(tempmax>*max)
                *max=tempmax;
            if(tempmin<*min)
                *min=tempmin;
        }
        */


    }
```

Comment: Can't understand your code. What is commented, what is not?

Comment: Also, the `min` and `max` variables in `main` don't actually point anywhere.  You should declare them as `int` instead of `int *`, and call `maximum(a,number,&max,&min)`, and not dereference them in the following `printf`.

Comment: Note that the cast of `(int*)` is not needed in `a = (int*)calloc(number,sizeof(int));`.  Curious: why was it coded that way?

Answer (score 1):

In your code [apparently commented], inside `void maximum()` function, `int i` is not initialized and afterwards, by mistake, instead of initializing `=`, you're comapring `==` and using value of `i`. [Read-before-write scenario]. With uninitialized `i`, `a[i]` can be very well produce undefined behaviour.

```
for(i==2;i<(n-2);i=i+2)
```

should be

```
for(i=2;i<(n-2);i=i+2)
     ^
     |
```

In the same function, you have used `int *max` and `int *min`, dereferencing them without any NULL check. From the `main()`, you're supplying uninitialized pointers. This is also undefined behaviour and can certainly cause segmentation fault.

Also, you never checked for the success of `scanf()`.

Then, never use `return(0);`from a function of which the return type is `void`. (thanks to @pat for below comment) .

Next, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`/ `calloc()`.

Comment: Or `return(0)` from a `void` function.

Comment: hey, thanks. what do you mean by  "Then, never user return(0);, as mentioned by @pat in below comment, from a function of which the return type is void."

Comment: @captainshai so sorry, typo. read it as `never use return(0)...` or have a look at my updated answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void maximum(int *a, int n, int *max, int *min);

    int main()
    {
        int i;
        int number;
        int max;
        int min;
        int *a;

        scanf("%d",&number);
        a = malloc(sizeof(int) * number);

        for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }


        maximum(a,number,&max,&min);
        printf("min is %d, max is %d",min,max);
        return(0);


    }

   void maximum(int *a, int n, int *max, int *min)
{
    int i,ma=a[0],mi = a[0],t1,t2;
    for(i=n%2;i<(n-1);i= i+2)
    {
            if(a[i] > a[i+1])
            {
              t1 = a[i];
              t2 = a[i+1];
            }
            else
            {
                t1 = a[i+1];
                t2 = a[i];
            }

            if(t1 > ma)
            ma = t1;

            if(t2<mi)
            mi = t2;
    }
    *max = ma;
    *min = mi;
}
```

Comment: This solution uses `2n` compares, as opposed to the `3n/2` compares that the OP was trying for.

Comment: @pat Cool will fix it

Comment: You may find `a = malloc(number * sizeof *a);` even a better style when calling `malloc()` and friends.  IMO, easier to code & maintain and less prone to error.

Comment: This and likely OP's code has trouble if `n` is even.  Consider `n==2`, `a[1]` is never accessed.  An easy fix would be `for(i=(n%2);i<(n-1);i= i+2)`

Comment: hey, thanks for all the answers, i will try again and hope it will work, by the way, i am new here, pls advise, does op stand for original program or as trash talk towards me?

Comment: @captainshai `Original poster` :) Be Happy nothing against you :)

Comment: hey chuks, thanks, but if i use malloc with (number * sizeof *a), wouldnt it allways give me for bytes as a pointer's space? will it do for a pointer to a long variable as an instance?

Comment: @captainshai Using malloc() you will get number of bytes needed to write to your array so you can do as shown in the code

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you have used == instead of = and i is not initialiazed before. So i has garbage value causing seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your program dies because you don't define *max and *min values when your comparation fails.
You need to add something like:

```
else
{
        *min=a[1];
        *mmax=a[0];
}
```

This won't solve your homework completely. If you want to find a maximum or minimum from a array, you must do some comparing inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help. 
these were the issues with the program, and for the (3n/2) part, the solution was to take each couple of  numbers, and to find a local min and max as following:

```
if(a>b)
  {
    max = a;
    min = b;
  } else 
  {
    max=b;
    min=a;
  }
```

and then compare every max with the following max and min to the following min as in

```
  if(max1>max2) 
    totalmax=max1;
  else 
    totalmax=max2;
```